# VBA StrComp never returns 0

Tags: string, vba, excel, string-comparison

I have a problem using the `StrComp` Function in VBA to compare two Strings.

```
Public Function upStrEQ(ByVal ps1 As String, ByVal ps2 As String) As Boolean       
    upStrEQ = False
    If StrComp(ps1, ps2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        upStrEQ = True
    End If

    If Len(ps1) = Len(ps2) Then
        Debug.Print ps1 & vbNewLine & ps2 & vbNewLine & upStrEQ
    End If

End Function
```

Debug output:

```
Technischer Name
Technischer Name
Falsch
```

As you can see the two strings have the same length and equal text but `upStrEQ` is `False` and `StrComp` did not return 0.

Any help would be nice. Thanks.

**Update:**
Since one of the Strings being passed to the function is read from a cell before I made a sample document so you can reproduce my error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yh6d4h8zxz533a/strcompareTest.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: there could be any hidden character like `paragraph end` . Are you sure there isn't anything like that? Try to test length of the text with `Len(string)` additionally.

Comment: Can you paste the value of `ps1` and `ps2` into the question.  We can then have a look to see whether there are any UniCode characters, etc, that could be confusing things.  (We can't do that with just an image.)

Comment: Can't download from your dropbox link so I can't verify the inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StrComp()` works quite nice. The problem is with your input, probably you have a hidden space or a new line.

Test your code like this:

```
Public Function upStrEQ(ByVal ps1 As String, ByVal ps2 As String) As Boolean

    If StrComp(ps1, ps2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        upStrEQ = True
    End If

    If Len(ps1) = Len(ps2) Then
        Debug.Print ps1 & vbNewLine & ps2 & vbNewLine & upStrEQ
    End If

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print upStrEQ("a", "a")

End Sub
```

Furthermore, the default value of a boolean function is false, thus you do not need to set it at the beginning.

In order to clean a bit your input, only to letters and numbers, you can use a custom `RegEx` function. Thus, something like this would always return letters and numbers:

```
Public Function removeInvisibleThings(s As String) As String

    Dim regEx           As Object
    Dim inputMatches    As Object
    Dim regExString     As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regEx
        .pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True

        Set inputMatches = .Execute(s)

        If regEx.test(s) Then
            removeInvisibleThings = .Replace(s, vbNullString)
        Else
            removeInvisibleThings = s
        End If

    End With

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print removeInvisibleThings("aa1 Abc 67 ( *^ 45 ")
    Debug.Print removeInvisibleThings("aa1 ???!")
    Debug.Print removeInvisibleThings("   aa1 Abc 1267 ( *^ 45 ")

End Sub
```

In your code, use it when you are passing the parameters `ps1` and `ps2` to the `upStrEQ`.

Comment: With your input everything works but with mine it doesn't. I thought that there should not be any hidden space or new lines since the strings have the same length? If not so how could I check for any invisible String content?

Comment: @daniel17903 - you can clean a bit your input, before passing it to the `upStrEQ` function. See the `removeInvisibleThings()`.